# .htaccess Options -Indexes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using a simple .htaccess file with the contents

Options -Indexes

to try and hide directory listings. However, when I try to load any page from the browser it gives me a 403 error for any page. Any ideas what the problem is?

For context, .htaccess is in the root folder that contains php files and folders of other php files included/required etc. by those in root.

Thanks in advance

Ben

Comment: Show the full .htaccess here. Also try removing parts of htaccess, until it starts working, minimizing our efforts.

Comment: Does it give that error when you turn off that option? Does apache's user on the server have access to your files on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a proper directory index setting. The `Indexes` option simply tells apache to display the contents of the directory as the index if there isn't a default index in that directory.

So if you have the file:

```
/index.php
```

Make sure you have:

1. A valid index file
2. it is part of the list defined by `DirectoryIndex`
3. It is readable by apache.

If your index.php is the file you want serves when the request is for the directory, then make sure it is readable by apache (644 is **good enough**), then make sure it's in the list defined by the directory index:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

One other thing that may be happening, and it's very specific to someone's website setup. If you have `DirectorySlash Off` somewhere, meaning apache won't automatically redirect the browser when a trailing slash is missing when a reqeust is for a directory, and you have `Indexes` turned off, then *your index file will get ignored*.

Example, if I have directory slash off, and a request for the directory is made:

```
/folder
```

without the trailing slash, it doesn't matter if you have a valid index file, *it will get ignored without a trailing slash*. If this is the case, make sure you really want to have trailing slashes removed for accesses to directories and this is a limitation of apache.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was due to permissions. CHMOD it to 777 or whatever.

Also, consider this rule is run for each page load. For speed purposes you can create .htaccess for each folder.

Comment: `0777` is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your folder permissions, you should check them